# How to override model in EXTJS and add extra field?

Tags: extjs, model, overriding

How to override model in EXTJS?
For example, if I have a model defined as:

```
Ext.define('Mypp.model.Class1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'field1',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    getField1: function() {
        return this.data.field1;
    },

    setField1: function(field1) {
        this.set('field1', field1);
    },
});
```

how can I override it and add extra field ```field3``

For example, how to override the following class and add extra field(s)?

```
Ext.define('Ext.calendar.model.Event', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    mixins: ['Ext.calendar.model.EventBase'],

    fields: [{
        name: 'title',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'color',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    getColor: function() {
        return this.data.color;
    },

    getTitle: function() {
        return this.data.title;
    },

    setColor: function(color) {
        this.set('color', color);
    },

    setTitle: function(title) {
        this.set('title', title);
    }
});
```

I tried

Comment: Override or extend? Why do you need getField and setField methods?

Comment: I would like to override (or extend, I am not sure)  the ```'Ext.calendar.model.Event'``` class that has defined eight fields ('title', 'calendarId', 'color', 'description', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'allDay', 'duration'), but I would like to add two more.

Comment: @Arthur - I updated the question and added refactored code for 'Ext.calendar.model.Event' class.

Comment: Are you using modern oder classic toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t understand why you need this, but anyway:

```
Ext.define('Mypp.model.Class1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [{
        name: 'field1',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    getField1: function() {
        return this.data.field1;
    },

    setField1: function(value) {
        this.set('field1', value);
    },
});

Ext.define('overrides.model.Class1', {
    override: 'Mypp.model.Class1',

    fields: [{
        name: 'field1',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'field2',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    getField2: function() {
        return this.get('field2');
    },

    setField2: function(value) {
        this.set('field2', value);
    }
});

model = new Mypp.model.Class1();
model.setField1('Field1Value');
model.setField2('Field2Value');
console.log(
    model.getField1(),
    model.getField2()
);
```